# For BIOS, Does Intel support both BIOS Reference Design and Firmware Support Package?

Tags: bios

When doing BIOS development, I see references to both the Intel BIOS Reference Design and the Intel Firmware Support Package (FSP).   Does Intel actively support both, or is the reference design being phased out in favor of FSP.

Answer (score 1):

To create FSP all the work that the reference code does was moved to the PEI phase. Previously some of the work was done in the DXE phase, and there is still some work done there for platforms that boot the UEFI way, but all the work required to make the platform operational is done in the PEI. These PEIM are then packaged into the FSP, such that an OS that is knowledgeable about FSP can continue the boot. The way that the UEFI FW passes control to the OS is different for UEFI or FSP boot, with some different interfaces; but the initialization code is the same.

It was all done this way so that there could be one reference code that would support either FSP or UEFI boot.

Some details may depend on the actual platform, as not all platforms support FSP, although the trend is for platforms to add support for FSP. So, in the long term it looks like both will be available for most platforms, but this is just a tread statement, not a representation of company position.